# Add jar downloaded from xyz url directly into gitlab(gitlab-ci.yml) artifact

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on CI/CD setting for maven project. In which all dependent jars getting download into .m2 of gitlab from repository. However one of my required jar are not present in the repository, that I am having in my local window system.

How I can add that jar into the gitlab artifact from my local system or from some external url? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your GitLab job is executed on a runner that has access to the Internet, then you can download files directly in your job:

```
myjob:
  script:
    - wget http://example.com/path/to/myjar.jar
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - myjar.jar
```

If your running is running powershell:

```
myjob:
  script:
    - Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.com/path/to/myjar.jar" -OutFile myjar.jar
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - myjar.jar
```

You can also add wget/Invoke-WebRequest into your normal build jobs, to be able to get it into the same artifact as the rest of your build.